# Cross Thread Operation - Invoked function calls another function C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a program which uses many threads, when one of the threads found an answer (I think the context doesn't really matter) - it announces it, and then the first thread I created calles a function in a user control class using Invoke.
I checked - and if I change any attributes in this function, I do not get the cross-thread operation. But this function starts a timer (System.Timers.Timer) -> so the function of the "Elapsed" event is called. Inside it I am trying to change an attribute, and that causes cross-thread operation. What am I doing wrong? Isn't it possible to have the invoked function calling another function and then change the attributes in there?

By the way, is it wrong to invoke functions using the delegate? I mean, having the delegate as an attribute of the class I need it in, and then using delegAttributeName.Invoke(parameters) - and not this.Invoke(new Delegate(), parameters);

Heres part of the code:

Thats is where I invoke the function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Nim_Assignment_3
{

public delegate void drawDeleg(Color c, int amount, int rowNumber);

public partial class Nim : Form
{
    private event drawDeleg myDrawDeleg;

    private void CheckXor()
    {
      if (this.foundToPaint)
            {
                this.myDrawDeleg.Invoke(this.currentTurnColor, this.amountToPaint, this.rowToPaint);
                this.drawWait.WaitOne();
                this.foundToPaint = false;
                if (this.currentTurnColor == Color.Blue)
                    this.currentTurnColor = Color.Red;
                else
                    this.currentTurnColor = Color.Blue;
            }

    }

  // the invoked function:
  private void callFillPencils(Color c, int amount, int rowNumber)
  {
          this.rows[rowNumber].fillPencils(c, amount);
  }
 }
}
```

And this is the function that the invoked function is calling - and the one it calls (the timer-elapsed event function):
(fillPencils - the function that the invoked function in the Form class (Nim) is calling):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace Nim_Assignment_3
{
public partial class PencilsUC : UserControl
{
    private PictureBox[] pencils;
    public static Image grayPencil = new Bitmap("GrayPen.bmp"), bluePencil = new    Bitmap("BluePen.bmp"), redPencil = new Bitmap("RedPen.bmp");
    private int amountOfPencils, amountOfPencilsLeft, currIndex, currAmount;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private Color currColor;
    public event FinishedDrawing drawFinishedDeleg;

    public PencilsUC()
    {
        // intializing things in the constructor...

        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this.timer.Interval = 100;
        this.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // THE THING THAT MAKES THE CROSS THREAD-OPERATION: THE LINE INSIDE THE "if"
        if (this.currColor == Color.Blue)
            pencils[currIndex--].Image = bluePencil;
        else
            pencils[currIndex--].Image = redPencil;

        this.currAmount--;

        if (this.currAmount == 0)
        {
            this.timer.Stop();
            if (this.drawFinishedDeleg != null)
                this.drawFinishedDeleg.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void fillPencils(Color c, int amount)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        this.currColor = c;
        this.currAmount = amount;
        this.timer.Start();
    }
}
```

}

(THE CROSS THREAD OPERATION HAPPENS INSIDE THE TIMER_TICK FUNCTION)

I used the windows forms timer at first but for some reason it didn't get to the tick-event function (timer.Start() was called but I put a message box in the tick function and it didnt get in there so I changed it - I saw some answers that said it was better)

I would love some help, I am sorry for the long post, I just wanted to be as clear as I can...

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to .Invoke onto the main thread to change any controls.

```
Image image;
if (this.currColor == Color.Blue)
    image = bluePencil;
else
    image = redPencil;

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => pencils[currIndex--].Image = image));
```

The => is the syntax for a lambda (called anonymous method in other languages). Think about it as a one-line function.

```
() => pencils[currIndex--].Image = image
```

is the same as:

```
void SetImage(Image image, ref int currIndex) {
    pencils[currIndex--].Image = image;
}
```

[MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) provides a simple delegate that is used to invoke a method with a void parameter list

Comment: Thank you! That worked. What does the "=>" does? If you can explain this whole line it would be nice, the MethodInvoker and the syntax... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's pretty clear now and it works :) Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with the Windows.Forms.Timer (it doesn't get to the tick event function)?

Comment: Without firing up the code, my initial guess would be either that the time isn't started, or something is blocking the timer tick event.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of a `System.Timers.Timer`.  (You'll need to change the names of a few properties/events, i.e. `Tick` instead of `Elapsed`, but it's straightforward enough.)

The Timer in the Form's namespace marshals the `Tick` event into the UI thread, unlike the systems timer which executes the event in a thread pool thread.

If you really prefer to use the system's timer, then you can set the `SynchronizingObject` to have it marshall it's event to the UI thread:

```
timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

Note that the UserControl is a synchronizable object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know why, but when I am using the Windows.Forms.Timer, the program just doesn't get to the tick event function (I put a message box there and it didn't show). Also, when I use the syncronizingObject I don't get the cross-thread operation, it stops in the middle. (My program paints - puts a colored image - in picture boxes. it is supposed to fill them all - it does if i use the invoke Dan Morphis suggested in his comment below - but using the synchronizingObject it stops for some reason...)

Comment: @Odedg Either you're blocking the UI thread, thus preventing the handler from running, you weren't starting the timer, or you weren't adding the proper handler (or possibly something more obscure).  Without seeing the code, specifics can't really be given.

Comment: (Please also watch my comment, I edited it).
The UI thread is the main thread, right? Can you tell me how can I block it? (Then I'll look if I did that). I am using Auto Reset Events to synchronize between my threads, do they also interrupt my main thread?

Comment: @Odedg If you're having the main thread doing a blocking wait on the results of something else then yes, that's a problem, and you almost certainly shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I am not sure if I did, I didn't mean to... Can you tell me what could possibly block it so I'll know what to search in my code that might cause a problem? Can the auto reset events I am using block it? (And how?) Thanks!

Comment: But what do you mean by anything? What could I do wrong that will block the UI thread? I didn't mean to, and I guess it doesn't "just" happen...

Comment: @Odedg It happens when the UI thread is running code that doesn't give up control quickly.  It could be anything from long running CPU operations, IO, waiting on something else, literally anything that takes time.

Comment: @Servy - so you've got your 55.6k just by answering first and then updating your answer with other's people answers just to ensure no one gets the points except you? Well, congratulations on your score then....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix as you already made code would be to set SynchronizingObject of the Timer to Form, so timer would run on UI thread.

Comment: The timer is in the user control class, did u mean to set the SynchronizingObject of the timer to this => to the user control?
And also, as you can see in what I wrote in comments to Servy's answer, the synchronizingObject does solves the cross-thread operation, but the painting stops in the middle for some reason (it doesn't happen with Dan Morphis's answer). Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, any object from Ui is fine for SynchronizingObject

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any idea then for why is it stopping in the middle?

Comment: Never mind, the problem was somewhere else in my code. Thank you very much - it works now :) If you have any idea why it doesn't reach my timer-tick function (of the tick event) when I use Windows.Forms.Timer please tell me :)

Comment: I believe that you've got three answers here which are generally correct, so you should chose which one was the best and accept that as answer by clicking check sign in it....

Comment: Haha ok thanks, and by the way I don't think Servy copied from you... Relax haha he edited his comment before you posted yours, and both (and Dan's) were helpful, thanks :)